# What is the equivalent of Solaris's passwd command in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

What is the equivalent of Solaris's `passwd` command in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

Linux passwd(1) uses the -S option /instead/ of the -s option.

In Solaris
  passwd -as

In Linux
  passwd -aS

Answer (score 2):

`passwd` , unless I'm missing something.